# Add "follow discussion" button for answer/comments

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Following [that post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125208/when-exactly-do-i-get-comment-notifications) I'd like to suggest a `follow discussion` button that if checked, will notify me on **any** new activity on a question I've commented/answered on

[image]

The reasoning for this is simple:

1. Many new users don't know that they need to add `@` in front of a users name and thus, when addressed, I many times don't even know about it.
2. When participating in some interesting discussion, I want to see the general comments (not only addressed to me) or other answers besides mine.

I know that I can mark the question as "favorite", but I find it rather very tedious to go over and over my comments or favorites in order to see "what's new".

Thus, I think it could be a very good option (for people interested in this service) that will save many people headache and time

Comment: This sounds like a question that belongs on http://meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I wish there were a way to offer a bounty on feature requests like this. This "follow discussion" feature is exactly what I keep wishing for. It'd be nice to get a solid yes or "no, that's too much work to implement" from the SE devs...

Comment: Many users post a (first) question and comments are used to instruct them how to improve them. This is done hours or days later. Unless the user explicitly mentions the commented in comments, this question could be "lost". It would be great to have this feature. So far I'm using the RSS feed but it would be easier if it was a site-level feature.

Comment: Would this encourage extended discussion in comments?  I'd use a feature like this, but, admittedly, I'm chattier than I should be.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that for Chrome users there is a an app on [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/493/stackstalker-be-notified-when-your-question-is-updated-chrome-extension) that does exactly that for long ago now. It can be installed directly from [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackstalker/paoeolblihedcagbofkkkecjilmpehmo)

Comment: Downvoted. Who the hell uses chrome anyways?

Comment: @JanDvorak Are you OK? If yes see **[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers)** and **[This](http://gs.statcounter.com/#all-browser-ww-monthly-201602-201602-bar)**.

Comment: @sandeep jk, ofc. But I still can't use it for I use Firefox.

Comment: @JanDvorak similar situation with me,  i don't use firefox in windows  and don't use chrome in ubuntu. .

Comment: @Sandeep Why not? I'm using Chromium on Ubuntu...

Comment: @DavidArenburg Just a personal preference.