# Yet another disgruntled new user

Tags: discussion, new-users, behavior

The community must have an attitude problem to get comments like this one (now deleted), which was on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19306428/256196):

> I did look [for a duplicate], but I didn't see that one in the query that was returned, so thank you for being polite about [making me aware of it]. A lot of people on here are a bunch of stuck up assholes, which is why I rarely ask a question on this site. I always get the "know it all" who thinks everyone is stupid unless they do everything perfect.

Note that the user's sentiment was not about his experience with that particular question though, but about his previous experience with the site in general.

This is not an isolated case, and I believe the sentiment is felt more often than expressed, too.

Can we commission a roving band of concierges or something?
Can we create a badge for "being <strike>nice</strike> helpful"?
Should we have a "<strike>nice</strike>helpometer" reading on user profiles?

or!

**Should we advertise harder about how to write good questions/answers?**

What's causing the attitude problem in some (seemingly a growing number of) users?

Comment: There's no context for the comment that you point out. [I've seen 2-3 disgruntled users here on Meta last night](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267969/456814), but they got back exactly what they put in, so I have little sympathy, at least for those 2-3 random cases.

Comment: Remember last time we tried being nice? Because I do, and things got worse.

Comment: This is a good discussion to have, and it seems there are things afoot here... but it's so hard to measure and classify these things, unfortunately

Comment: @Cupcake added link to question (first sentence). The question wasn't great, but it's not *that* relevant because he's talking about his previous experience with the site, not his experience with that question (which ironically was good).

Comment: Last night there were lot of disgruntled users, some on @Cupcake's post, [one here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267981/downvoting-should-be-justified#comment73878_267981), [one here who edited rude words into his post until Bill finally locked it](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25174354/8). I too feel sympathy for them and try to help if the issue is solvable, but that doesn't require badges for niceness IMO. Politeness and good behavior can't be taught or inspired by badges.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion the boy scouts have [a badge for good manners](http://www.boyscouttrail.com/cub-scouts/acadsports/goodmanners.asp). Maybe we can adopt something like that.

Comment: @Bohemian, we tried. It did not work. For a while it looked like the site was a "better" place and friction occurred less, but we ended up with questioners with a sense of entitlement so strong *anything* we said was met with resentment, as well as answerers who thought being nice meant answering all the crap questions under the sun. All in all, not a good deal IMHO.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion, I disagree. Politeness can be inspired by badges and taught if other users make it a point to be teachers. I was taught good/polite behavior by a very similar system called - Mom and Dad don't put up with that crap.

Comment: Also, not everyone agrees on what exactly being nice means. Especially when it extends to culture. Some people think being nice means calling everyone dear, love, friend, brother, buddy, when it's just informal, flowery, noisy and awkward. I have no interest in the site being polluted with flowery chatty comments being posted just for the sake of getting a badge.

Comment: More context: [Kicking off the Summer of Love](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/); [Week 2 of the Summer of Love: Researching Comments](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/week-2-of-the-summer-of-love-researching-comments/); [What is Stack Overflow’s goal?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254973/456814); [How can Stack Overflow improve rule visibility and user experience?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267953/456814).

Comment: @BoltClock On the flip side, you can be direct without being rude. This isn't an "either rude or nice" kind of binary situation. While you're right in saying that there is no one true standard for "nice", nice doesn't have to mean "flowery chatty language". There's a balance to be found here and to be perfectly honest, in my experience, people who argue the hardest against being nice are the ones who care the least about phrasing their points using neutral-ish language. Having said that, I agree that a badge would be hard to define/over the top in this case.

Comment: I can't believe I'm linking to this `:P` [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758/456814).

Comment: @Anna Lear: That is true. I'm just saying that a good number of people think being nice *does* mean being chatty (and sometimes even off-topic). We already deal with enough chatty comments as it is, and we don't need more, especially for a badge that, like you said, is difficult to define anyway.

Comment: @BoltClock By "being nice" I really mean "be professional", ideally "helpful" or simply "don't be abrasive/rude". Pretty basic stuff - how people should interact in general. I expect the same in return. It doesn't mean "put up with effortless/rubbish posts", rather if you see something borderline, help it come back from the edge rather than push it off.

Comment: @BoltClock I hear ya. Although as a moderator, I'd rather handle chatty comments than "omg this was offensive to me!" type of flags on comments that are *technically* correct but also pretty abrasive. The former just seems easier overall, so that'd be a win-win for everyone on balance. :)

Comment: Parents are the foundation of our character @ChiefTwoPencils, but are you expecting users to parent  [13 year olds and above on SO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children's_Online_Privacy_Protection_Act)? I personally feel if a person doesn't learn politeness in _13 years of their "pre-SO" life_, a badge won't help much after that..

Comment: So, in my observations (and personal experience?), rudeness (or at least, insufficient neutral-ness or sugar-coating) arises out of frustration on the part of veteran users. Shog tried to address this in part by giving certain users [the Dupe Hammer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254590/456814), making it *easier* and less painful to moderate posts. I'm not sure if that was ultimately a good solution, or if anything else along those lines should be done.

Comment: Again, not everyone understands being nice simply means being professional and neutral. Although @Anna has a point in that we'd not rather deal with people being abrasive all the time.

Comment: @Infinite: Not really, but I think if you observe it you can take a couple sec.s and plead them not to be rude. A little can go a long way especially if the offender feels ostracized. I believe the supposed limit, according to those in-the-know, of a person truly changing their personality is around their mid-twenties, but I'm not trying to split hairs.

Comment: Robert had a [good explanation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253813/456814) about veteran frustration with moderation too.

Comment: **Attitude problem arises when new users don't bother to read that how to ask a question. And when downvoted and suggested by other long time users to follow some conventions for the website,they loose their minds.**

Comment: @DividebyZero too much bold `:P`

Comment: @DividebyZero - I totally agree. :)

Comment: @Cupcake Bold because I want this comment to make a loud noise..... it's one of the reason, why new users are drawing a bad view of the community in their minds.

Comment: To second @DividebyZero's opinion - check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25197096/how-to-trim-spaces-in-array-without-using-default-functions. It was screaming to be closed. PS: The question is *not* directed towards a particular person.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236537/lets-have-an-explicit-triage-system-for-questions-from-new-users/236540#comment775560_236540): "*From the perspective of Stack Overflow, there are simply many more people asking questions than there are people willing and able to hold their hands. Triage is 100x more important to SO than the welcome wagon - forget nice words to misguided people, SO needs more efficient [winnowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winnowing).*". Related: [Feedback requested: New “recommended” homepage, phase 1](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261138/456814).

Comment: Um, so how do you know that it's not just the *worst* users who complain the loudest?

Comment: Looks like the system worked as designed, to me.

Comment: [The *worst* users](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268123/yet-another-offensive-email-from-another-new-user-on-stack-overflow#comment74694_268132) tend to complain the loudest...

Comment: Me: ah, you're back from vacation.  Where did you go?  Colleague: Paris, wonderful city.  Too bad it has so many French people, rude lot.  Me: hmm, did you make any attempt at speaking French with them?  Colleague: nah, didn't bother to learn any, I wasn't planning to go back there anytime soon.

Comment: oh cmon. Though I've never insulted ppl on SO, sometimes I get really annoyed. How do you expect a developer to react, if, for example, folks keep asking intermediate-level android questions while absolutely lacking very basic java knowledge? Apart from the fact that the answer can be found like 20 times when using search for 1 minute

Comment: See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268054/545127

Comment: This community doesn't have an attitude problem. Half the world has an attitude problem. Post-internet culture promotes entitlement as a value. Also, for some reason in the past 20 years, true confidence has been on the out-and-out (I blame many things, will not rant) and consequently high levels of defensiveness due to e.g. defining self-image based on up/down-votes becomes common. There's nothing we can do about it except instill some confidence in our kids (their communication with others via the internet shortens our window there) and hope the internet is a better place in 30 years...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is essentially an XY problem, and the real question, "Why do people take things so personally?" is categorically too broad.

Comment: I wonder if getting the user base to be broader by encouraging more [women and minorities](http://royal.pingdom.com/2012/08/21/report-social-network-demographics-in-2012/) to join would improve either the quality of users of the site or cause people to act differently in their responses?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: This isn't just a StackOverflow thing; this is a growing trend in the software industry as a whole. I think that's something to be considered.

Comment: Why not edit his questions or just drop advice to push him in the right direction?  If stuff can't be answered, but attention is at least shown, he'll eventually bounty it.  If anything, *advertise harder about how to be a good answerer*.  Try `RTI` (reward to interact): a means of encouraging people to maintain their motivation, even when breaking the bad news that they've done something inappropriate.  This at least works twice as hard for you because critic behavior encourages new-user behavior by example.  Each tenured user may associate a cycle of friendship to software he or she uses.

Comment: I'd argue a growing number of bullies with experience, who are perhaps new to editing, would increase the growing number of unhappy new users.  It's difficult to manage that many "staff", none of whom were screened.  I have faith in the goodness of the human heart, but it may encourage users to edit early.  They can see more point-value rewards and honors as they come into the site, and their connectivity to the community may improve their attitude.  On the other hand, it's a nice mid-game discovery that keeps people motivated as they move up the ranks.  How about more mid-game rewards/goals?

Comment: @jasonc re X-Y: Maybe, but everyone takes a rebuke personally, it's just a matter of degree. The problem is people tend to bully by dismissive comments (or just VTC) rather than edit or give advice (ie help). New users are probably grappling with the format/use of the site, which is different from the most of the forum style Q+A sites out there, to read the fine print on how to ask - I think it's overload on the first post. Combine that with an intolerant community and you'll drive new users away; new users that in time could be positive contributors.

Comment: @Bohemian I disagree with some of that. In any case, perhaps a change as simple as having the gray instructional text in the comment box also say something about staying polite would reduce the edge on a lot of the comments. Or a popup reminder as a user begins typing a comment, for users that have had rude / non-constructive comments flagged recently. Jeff Atwood has [a nice article](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-just-in-time-theory/) that talks about the value of reminding people to be good at the last possible second, and how that's put to use on SE sites.

Comment: Did I miss something, or is this about a question from last year?

Comment: @AnnaLear well, there are users that think that *downvoting* is being rude... which is ridiculous, and me telling them that is also rude... in their eyes.

Comment: I've had multiple instances of people calling me names on here and subsequently systematically downvoting my (previous) questions / answers - ones that had been closed.   I've mostly stopped using the site b/c it's so unpleasant on average.   So, yes, there's a problem.

Comment: The solution's easy. Provide 1-on-1 counselling to everybody who is downvoted on SO or any other SE site. It's for their own good.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi "things got worse" citation needed.

Answer (score 108):

Based on the comments, and also on previous discussions I've seen about related topics, some people seem to believe that being polite automatically means tolerating bad questions. I don't subscribe to this point of view at all. I think it's perfectly possible to treat people who post poorly written questions with respect, and still enforce high standards.

When I comment on questions that have problems, I tend to be pretty direct about what exactly is needed. I don't call anybody "dear" or "buddy" (to borrow some words from @BoltClock's comment above). I might sometimes use the word "please", but that's about as far as the formalities go. But I always try to keep the comments on the matter, and not say anything that could be interpreted as personal. I commonly see comments that look downright rude, and I don't think there's a need for that.

The response is almost exclusively positive. If I leave a comment that says something like:

> You say that "it does not work". We need more detail to be able to help. Can you please add the exact error message?

In response, most posters will add the missing information, and sometimes even apologize for missing it initially. Mission accomplished, without any bad feelings for anybody.

It's really very similar to professional communication used in person. Many companies these days encourage very direct and open communication. It's accepted and encouraged to point out problems with other people's work, speak up when you disagree with somebody else's point of view, etc. But that's never an excuse to tolerate insults or personal attacks. There's a big difference between criticizing somebody's work with valid technical points, and personal insults. In my opinion, it makes complete sense to apply the same standards in an online community like this one.

Comment: this approach seems to be pretty similar to what was discussed in [On large communities decaying over time, being nice or mean, and Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256003/839601) "the first and most crucial step toward allowing a site of this size to function is to discourage the sorts of interpersonal connections that would tie it down"

Comment: Some of the problem is perception. Some people will perceive that what you said, even in your example comment above, you're being mean to them.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: That's certainly possible. I haven't really experienced it first hand. Of course I don't have a huge amount of data. It looks like I used a total of about 700 comments so far. I can't easily find out how many of them were asking for clarification/improvement on questions, but I figure it must be at least 100-200. As far as I can remember, I have never gotten a very negative reaction. I've seen it happen second hand that an OP went off the deep end with very little provocation. But based on what I've observed, that's more the exception than the rule.

Comment: @RetoKoradi but are the extreme outlier exceptions the ones that are getting a [disproportionate amount of attention](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268099/yet-another-disgruntled-new-user#comment74529_268099)?

Comment: @Cupcake: Maybe. You would almost have to look at each case. I suspect that you would find a mix. I have seen comments directed at newbies that were unnecessarily harsh/rude, including words like "stupid". I think they have every right to be upset, because they absolutely should not be treated this way. But there's certainly also a (small) number that simply can't handle negative feedback, even if it's well founded and presented in a polite manner. There's probably not much we can (or should) do about that second category of posters. They were probably on the wrong site.

Comment: Users who call newbies stupid and leave extremely rude comments are infact a reality. They push new users to the edge. The rants we get on Meta are a clear reflection that rudeness is on the rise and manners are decaying.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion this doesn't seem to be widespread in questions receiving sufficient attention (I saw rude comments disappearing even faster than I could flag them, and I consider self decently quick on flagging). In close queue rude comments seem to be exceedingly rare, even though of questions I reviewed so far 3-4 thousands looked _offensively bad_. It is as if users voting close also take time to flag rude comments

Comment: Even more fun are the users who think the sites rules are dumb, and then take your attempt to inform them (politely) about the rules as a personal attack and an opportunity to complain about said rules. This from a user with 50 rep (not high, but not 1 either).

Comment: Just the phrase "tolerate bad questions" is indicative of the problem.  Folks, it is a tech website, not taxation without representation.

Comment: the violence is not in the language. it's in the downvoting and the closing. it's systemic in SO and won't be solved by nature of the gamification choices

Comment: @v.oddou That makes it sound like people just take issue with the site being moderated with high quality standards in general. Do they also call your teacher violent for giving them a failing grade? Or lash out at journal editors for rejecting their manuscript? The downvoting and closing is not that aggressive in the face of all the subpar questions arriving each day. Note also that there are 7 times more upvotes than downvotes in the site.

Comment: @E_net4 teachers rarely create negative grades. And yes there are some research attempting to eliminate grades in the school cursus because of their violence. Already in application in France since 2014 at teachers's discretion. 7:1 ratio is horribly low, nothing to be proud of.

Comment: @v.oddou Alas, the ratios do not have to align, given the different circumstances. This is an international platform where every user starts with the privilege to ask a question, and their expectations about the site are too often way off.

Answer (score 31):

I agree that some users are a-gruntling. I'm not sure whether this is a recent thing or not, these things fluctuate and come and go anyway. In a community as ginormous as SO/SE, it's inevitable to have disgruntled people. Even in a super happy community, the least happy people would be the gruntlers. So, this phenomenon by definition won't go away entirely and it's no reason to bend over backwards every time one surfaces.

Having said that, it's always a good opportunity to reevaluate one's current position. Based purely on anecdotal evidence, I get the feeling that people are easily getting disgruntled because they put a lot of assumptions into other people's words. Something along the lines of all close-voters being jerk-offs on power trips, people riding high horses being know-it-alls and enjoying themselves scoffing at others and other such sentiments. Negative feedback is being attributed to these things instead of taken at face value, which of course will quickly leave you with a feeling of SO being a place full of rectal orifices.

Now, is this true? Are we close voting and down voting and critiquing due to these reasons? Obviously I cannot speak for everyone, but again based purely on anecdotal evidence I will say that this is false. I am one of these hi-rep Mjölnir wielders, and I will say that I do not derive any personal satisfaction from wielding it. I participate in SO because I find it interesting. Looking at other people's problems and finding solutions to them is something that tickles my fancy, that's why I'm here. That's why I have a ridiculously high number of unicorn points amassed over the years. I am not gaming the system for the purpose of getting rep, I am not pleasuring myself by voting one way or another, I do none of these things. I enjoy explaining random stuff to people, which is exactly what SO is for, which is why I happen to do pretty well here.

Now, why do I down vote or close vote? Because some sh*t absolutely makes no friggin' sense. Seriously. I have answered the most obtuse questions based on a combination of experience and gut feeling and I'm pretty often right. But some questions even I look at and my eyes just glaze over. I am trying to be very liberal and really do *help* people. But sometimes the best thing I can do with a question is to close it, tell the OP that I've closed it because of A, B or C, and to recommend him to try again. If at all possible I'll even go out of my way to nudge them in the right direction, so the next time they try they may have better ground to stand on. If somebody interprets that as rude, there's nothing anybody can do to help them.

As a user of SO, you need to realise that you're not talking to a Google bot. You're talking to other people. You're not going to get an answer if you just string random keywords together. Always imagine you're barging in on a group of colleagues at the coffee machine with your question. You're not automagically going to get a great answer from them, regardless of the quality of your question. You need to communicate well what you want in order to get what you want. If all you get from that coffee group is some **mumble*mumble*RTFM*mumble** that's likely not because those guys are dicks, but because you failed to engage them with your problem. And sometimes it does mean that the answer *is* to RTFM, there's no larger problem to solve than that. If you do it right and you manage to engage a person with your problem, your chances are good to get great in-depth answers, because we *want* to answer. But that is not a right, privilege or guarantee; it's the result of good communication.

Now, are we being rude? Everybody can be perceived as such sometimes. I'm striving not to come across as rude. But written communication fails often. Comment space is limited here, time is limited, sometimes that leads to a terse, neutral response being interpreted as abrasive.

If you're feeling disgruntled, ask yourself whether you're interpreting too much into the intentions of someone. Never attribute to maliciousness what can adequately be explained by other means. If you're told you're being rude, introspect a bit and try not to be.

Comment: In my personal experience, the users who are most likely to complain and misinterpret neutral help as being "rude" are also the most misguided, [with no understanding of how the site works](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/267974/1), and are the least willing to look to see if the problem might be themselves, if at all.

Comment: [This is a less extreme example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267950/456814): "*I imagine that the moderator who struck me down was undoubtedly just doing his job, but their attitude (I'm not naming names) was abhorrent to any kind of respect and understanding. Instead of taking the time to educate me, they had just slapped the red tape on and moved on.*".

Comment: These were the comments that were left for the OP: "*Please read [stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) - link only answers aren't considered valid answers for Stackoverflow.*" and "*While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.*". "Abhorrent" indeed `<eye-roll>`.

Comment: I thought the verb 'gruntle' meant to be happy? It's the dis-gruntlers who are complaining.

Comment: What is "a-gruntling"? Does "a" mean "army"?

Comment: @halfer My dictionary says "disgruntled" comes from "to grunt" (negative meaning), with "dis-" being an *intensifier* instead of a negator.

Comment: @Peter Nope, just my wordplay, along the lines of "aflame". :)

Comment: I am displeased and dismayed at all this gruntling. In another words, I am very pleased and very mayed.

Comment: People aren't easily disgruntled because they put a lot of assumptions into other people's words. People are easily disgruntled because 1) post-internet culture promotes entitlement as a value, and 2) for some reason in the past 20 years, true confidence has been on the out-and-out (I blame many things, but not an appropriate rant here) and consequently high levels of defensiveness due to e.g. defining self-image based on up/down-votes becomes common. There's nothing we can do about it except instill some confidence in our kids and hope the internet is a better place in 30 years.

Comment: @Jason Very interesting analysis, and likely very apt too. On the surface people are blaming things on what I mentioned, but on a deeper level they do it because of what you say.

Comment: I asked myself "whether I'm interpreting too much", and the answer I gave myself was: Maybe, but I shouldn't have to interpret at all. Just _tell me politely_. (PS - I wasn't talking about myself personally obviously, but about any disgruntled user).

Answer (score 22):

There's a variety of things at play.

People want to strongly identify with - and become part of - something that they deeply believe in. They want to be part of something bigger than themselves, something likely to last, something that's doing some good. That's what they see when they look at the site, while someone stumbling through the first few chapters of their beginner's guide to Java just sees a place they can type questions and get answers; it's this discrepancy that can cause things to deteriorate:

... ***Do you even debug, bro?***

***You're being rude!***

... ***No, you're being flippant, Can't you see I'm trying to help you?!***

***All I did was ask a question! Can't you just answer it without berating me?***

... ***YOU AND YOUR KIND ARE RUINING THE INTERNET!***

It basically goes downhill from there. Put simply, the middle ground between people that come here to *give* something and people that come here to *get* something isn't yet centered properly. The person asking didn't realize that they just walked into someone's church with muddy feet, and the person greeting them didn't realize their pillow fort only looks like a castle to the kids that helped to build it.

The other thing to consider is the way people learn how to program has *fundamentally* changed over the last 20 years, more so than ever in the last five. We're effectively slashing the time it takes for someone with the potential *to be* competent to get up and running with a language - *if* they can learn how to communicate effectively.

Yet, some equate someone not struggling and suffering as much as *they* did to learn something with someone else being *lazy*, and that's a *tragic* mistake because it doesn't allow for the process to become *better*. I'll stop reiterating the obvious before we go walking to school uphill, in the snow, for 20 kilometers, with no shoes.

You can't force people to be *nice*, but you can ask that they not be *rude*. That's what I was hoping to get out of the summer of love - you don't need to go hugging everyone, but try to refrain from throwing mud every time you find yourself annoyed. It's *very* true that we spend only a few years of our lives learning how to talk, and the rest of it learning how to *shut the hell up* when it would well suit us to do so.

If you walk into enough people while texting your BFF on your way to work in lower Manhattan, *someone is going to tell you off*. Stack Overflow is a big city and any expectation that everyone is going to prefer silence over negativity is at *best* unrealistic. That doesn't mean we shouldn't continue to try and do something about it, but let's have realistic goals in mind.

Changes in help new users receive that ask ... *potentially okay* ... questions should help this significantly. At least, it should help to the point that if you're barked at, it's pretty easy to explain *why* and not hand-wave it off with 'they're just always rude to everyone!' (did you know that water is also fatal? 100% of the people that drink it eventually die). People *not* seeing stuff like:

> plz see dis codes and kindly supply ur fix

.. on the front page *at all* will help enormously. They'll be less inclined to lump someone that probably just didn't know what to search *for* in with someone that simply can't be bothered to earn their own paycheck.

I want to see if we manage to do everything we're setting out to do with the quality project ([MSO background](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/se-quality-project) | [MSE background](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/se-quality-project)) before we start considering other things. If I'm right, and while I'm wrong about lots of stuff I'm *usually* right about these sorts of things, the problem will right itself for the most part once we're done.

Still, you'll always have old geezers, and you'll always have lawns - however small - in this rapidly growing pillow fort we're building.

Comment: "(did you know that water is also fatal? 100% of the people that drink it eventually die)" So do 100% of the people who use Stack Overflow. brb suing

Comment: @BoltClock Studies have shown that among all SO users who have never taken a drink of water, none have died. SO may be a red herring.

Comment: +1 for "plz see dis codes and kindly supply ur fix"

Answer (score 16):

Since I tend to frequent PHP, SQL, VB and JavaScript tags I tend to see a large amount of low-quality questions from people who, quite frankly, have no idea how to program.

I can understand some of their frustration, they have a problem they can't solve, they come here for help, and all of a sudden their question gets put on hold as off topic, or too broad or flagged as a duplicate, sometimes with little to no explanation why. **Often though, it seems like they have no idea what this site is for. They seem to treat Stack Overflow as if it were some kind of service that they are entitled to.**

In general I try to be polite, so if I'm going to tag it off topic, I'll try to help them understand why, or I'll ask them to refine their question-- In the case of duplicates, in a few cases I've written my comment something like "Was this(some link) what you were looking for?" and if they can't get it try to help them a little bit, I see a lot of very high-rep users acting the same way. But we can't expect that behavior from every user-- after all, niceness isn't necessarily correlated with programming ability!

On the other hand, there was an hour today where at least 4 SQL questions involved the OP's not understanding how `JOIN`s worked, or that they were even a thing. Sure, it's tempting to be say STFU & RTFM, just out of sheer frustration at having to deal with 'stupid' questions. **I try to remind myself that I haven't always known what I know, and I still have lots to learn, and that helps me keep polite**. But it's not easy!

I think the issue is, there are a very large number of people who visit this site and ask questions

1. without doing a Google search of the question first.
2. without looking around Stack Overflow (though to be fair, Google seems better at finding related Stack Overflow questions than Stack Overflow is, the algorithm for searches needs to be worked on a bit IMO).
3. with only a basic knowledge of programming.

**Is it Stack Overflow's job to teach them how to program? I don't think so.**

**Can we help them to search better? I'm not sure if that will change their behaviour.**

Part of the issue is, anyone that does/has those three things is likely to already find an answer for a large range of newbie-ish questions, which leads to new questions in some tags being largely annoying to deal with. **Personally, if anything, I wish there was a better way to help prevent people from asking these sorts of questions, but it's kind of inevitable.**

There likely will always be people who don't know how to program, don't know what this site is for, and post all kinds of crazy questions. Unless and until we find some sort of algorithm to deal with them automatically, 'older' users are going to have to deal with them. Anyone in the customer service industry can tell you, there are always a fraction of people that are miserable to deal with. If they are a customer, you may have to suck it up. **But this is a *voluntary* help site. If anything, we need people to better understand that nobody on Stack Overflow has an obligation to help them. If they feel self-entitled enough to be upset about that, do you really think they will ever be good contributors to the community?**

Comment: We should flag, close, delete, in brief moderate and maintain quality of SO. But under any circumstance, we should be polite if we decide to engage in written communication with the user.

Comment: You can't make people better understand that because most people of that type only post a question once. People who rack up lots of questions and also post many answers -- the community contributors you refer to -- don't need to be made to understand that. They already do. I think your annoyance is understandable. You're like college professor being expected to teach third grade. But we can't choose in advance who can post questions and who can't.

Comment: @RobertSF: Your answer reminded me of this quote "The great tragedies of history occur not when right confronts wrong but when two rights confront each other"~Henry Kissinger. Unfortunately you deleted it. It was good.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Thanks. After a bit of reflection, I deleted it because I thought it was too preachy and I'm not well enough established here to preach yet. :) But thanks for thinking it was good.

Comment: Thanks @Quantas. My internal inline-code-as-general-emphasis antennae were going crazy this morning, that must have been why. They've quietened down a great deal now.

Comment: The phrase "have no idea how to program" covers a large span.  There are some fundamentals to programming, even though they are different emphases in different schools of thought.  Sometimes wildly different.  When I learned programming, in the early sixties, they didn't even teach structured programming, never mind object oriented programming.  Nevertheless, there are some points of common knowledge between those who learned the craft 50 years ago and those who learned it two years ago.

Comment: @RobertSF I agree we can't pick who posts questions but in general, that's a good thing. My point I guess is, do we need to care what one-time-terrible-question askers think about us? Is there some way we can assert our boundaries (e.g. what is and isn't acceptable) with those users?

Comment: @WalterMitty I know programming has changed dramatically over the last 40+ years and will likely change dramatically in the next 20+, however what I mean by "have no idea how to program" is people asking very basic questions that are covered by the simplest tutorials available on the internet. (like my JOIN example, or asking how to loop in javascript, how to program a website etc.)-- some of those questions already exist on the site, some are too broad, and some show that the person really should really learn more about the language before it's even possible to help them....

Comment: You and I are on the same page.  The point I was trying to make is about the "common knowledge".  That stuff changes very slowly, provided you understand it at the right level of abstraction.

Comment: **This is _not_ "a help site".** Other than that, +1.

Comment: You cannot hold an individual question-poster responsible for the fact that his errors/misunderstandings are common. Suppose it were just him/her - *and no other SO user at all.* ; would you treat him/her in a more friendly, less disgruntled way? If you even suspect the answer is 'Yes', just make the effort to treat him/her that way regardless.

Comment: @serakfalcon, you make a valid point about poorly asked questions. I often want to help other programmers, but lots of times the questions display a poor understanding and I am unclear as to whats being asked to the point where I can either not answer questions 99% of the time or try to give them the answer by walking through how things work and hope their answer is in that response or that my answer at least helps someone else, but I don't always have time. Perhaps there is a future for these posters in project management.

Answer (score 10):

All the current answers here provide different perspectives about "What's causing the attitude problem in some (seemingly a growing number of) users?"

I have been part of Stack Overflow for a few months now, and as a new user, I [regularly participate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=participation) in Meta to familiarize myself with the rules. During this process, I too, have seen some of the posts and comments which Bohemian mentioned in the question.

Moderation is important to maintain the quality of Stack Overflow and we should actively close, delete, flag all low quality and localized posts. But, *if* we decide to engage in written communication with other users via comments or posts, we should be polite. Even if someone has been rude or has done inadequate research, it doesn't justify our rude remarks.

I agree with [JasonC's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/616460/jason-c) [interesting observation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268099/yet-another-disgruntled-new-user/268322#comment75806_268121) about the underlying cause:

> People aren't easily disgruntled because they put a lot of assumptions into other people's words. People are easily disgruntled because
>
> 1. post-internet culture promotes entitlement as a value, and
> 2. for some reason in the past 20 years, true confidence has been on the out-and-out (I blame many things, but not an appropriate rant here) and consequently high levels of defensiveness due to e.g. defining self-image based on up/down-votes becomes common.
>
> There's nothing we can do about it except instill some confidence in our kids and hope the internet is a better place in 30 years.

I have come across a fair amount of rude posts and comments, which I actively edit and flag (having full edit privilege and 100 flags per day helps....). One observation has been that the rudeness is more prevalent in comments than in posts.

I am not sure about the effectiveness of new badges or niceometer, I think feedback may prove more effective in inspiring positive behavior. So I suggest the following:

- Introduce "-1" reputation to commentor for every rude comment.
  Users are actively flagging rude comments and getting them removed, but those who write such comments do not get any feedback. Hence, they continue the behavior. A small feedback may help in discouraging them. This is similar to the -100 reputation for posting spam. Spam is a bigger problem, so it has a bigger penalty. "-1" would be a gentle nudge for rudeness.
- Auto-alert moderators if a commentor gets correctly flagged for 100 rude comments.
  100 is an arbitrary number, it can be 50 or 500 based on the actual volume of rude comments. If a commentor is regularly rude in their conversations, a bit of moderator attention might help.

Comment: -1 for each "rude comment" is a nice thought. But .. would that also count for someone commenting "no i will *not* write code for you", which may be perceived as "rude" by (at least) the OP? (Resisting to add insults here, with an added "well, at -1 apiece you got 5000 more of those coming yer way!")

Comment: There are more condescending comments than rude ones, I believe. Also, would you replace downvotes-with-rude-comments by downvotes-with-no-comments? Finally, you're making the assumption that there a focal point to these problems in a small minority of rude users - and while there might be such a minority, it is extremely small and not IMO the cause for the sentiments OP reports.

Answer (score 8):

*The community must have an attitude problem to get a comments like this one* - I respectfully *disagree*.

A *similar* thing happened to me yesterday. There was a Java + [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) question (deleted after I flagged it as spam) to match URLs. The question wasn't clear at all. When we asked the OP to specify his exact input and expected output, he got pissed and started passing vulgar comments. He went on an abusing spree and passed a *very very bad* comment on one of the users who had asked *From where did you get this pattern?.* (The pattern which the OP had shown was wrong and the OP hadn't said what was the *expected* output, we were *assuming* some things about the output.) The OP's argument was that we were *actually *breaking* his *pattern*.

I've had my answers/questions deleted/closed a couple of times, yet I don't complain. If you are here to learn, you take it in the stride, accept that it was bad and try improving the next time. Several hundred questions are closed / removed everyday due to various reasons - people who are really interested in getting the answer really don't care if their question is marked as a duplicate, **all they care about is understanding the answer/concept**. The problem arises when **people with attitude problems post questions and expect answers to their poor questions**.

These *trolls* cannot be stopped. Yes, I agree that sometimes there will be mistakes, but seldom do I see a good post being closed / downvoted.

Comment: ***Encourage comments on downvotes*** , the system already does that! Have you lost your mind @theLostMind?

Comment: The edit made me change my +1 into a -1. Not closing duplicates? Seriously?

Comment: @iStimple- Indeed I lost it years back (Still looking for it :P)..  Guess what, I just tried downvoting the *other* answer on this post **without** a comment. Believe me, it worked.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch - My bad. I meant - *Discourage closing questions which are not exact duplicates*. edited the answer.

Comment: @iStimple, you're being ironically rude; please don't do that. :)

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils no he's not,he is just annotating the name of the answerer.

Comment: Ok.. Removed my *unacceptable* edit.. Never got so many down-votes for an answer :P

Comment: Why are you flagging legitimate (but poor quality/duplicate) questions as spam? That flag should be reserved for stuff that is actually, you know, spam.

Comment: @ChrisF - What??

Comment: @TheLostMind - To quote: "There was a Java + REGEX question (deleted after I flagged it as **spam**)" - (my emphasis). Why did you do this?

Comment: @ChrisF-  The OP went on to **personally** attack the people who had asked for expected output in the question. He took names, the question was abusing people.

Comment: @TheLostMind - that's still not spam. I understand why you flagged, but please make the moderator's job easier by using the appropriate flag. If you flag incorrectly - especially with one of the predefined flags - we may miss the real problem because we're looking for something else.

Comment: @ChrisF - I understand. Will make a note to use proper flags :)

Answer (score 6):

There was a [public service announcement](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tkCBlf6RznU) a while back simply showed a chain reaction of people helping each other, nothing really profound just small courtesies that seemed to make the recipient more inclined to be courteous to the next person.

Unfortunately these chain reactions work in both directions. While some one could hold the door for you, making you a little more inclined to help the next person, they could just as easily slam it in your face, making you a little less inclined to help the next person.

What has all this got to do with SO? Well, SO really relies on a sort of altruistic chain reaction to keep things moving along. When new users are greeted by more experienced users who honestly approach with a desire to be helpful, they become more inclined to be helpful to the users who come after them.

So... What things can we do differently to get more positive chains and less negative chains?

- **Don't pile on.** That isn't saying that you shouldn't downvote or vote
  to close, just don't be the 5th person to hassle the OP about whats wrong with the post. If you can't fix the post and someone has already left a comment asking for the required info, vote accordingly and leave it alone.
- **If you see things going wrong do something about it.** Rather than watching the train wreck step in and redirect things, or if need be flag it.
- **Don't patronize.** Don't leave condescending long-winded comments "welcoming" new users to the site just to tell them they're doing it wrong. Be genuine or don't bother.
- **Offer guidance.** Whenever possible try to offer guidance rather than criticism. There's a world of difference between "You're doing it wrong" and "You'll get better results doing it this way..."
- **Above all, if you're getting burnt out, walk away.** If you're tired of seeing crappy posts from crappy users, it's not just them, it's you (your perspective is crappy). Don't unload your frustration on the next OP who [wants to parse HTML with regex<sup>1</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). You've been starring at the screen for too long and its time for a break.

<sub><sub>1. Unless its really timelessly humorous... But you're not that funny, so just don't</sub></sub>

---

To more directly address the question...
I don't think offering badges, organizing welcoming committees, or advertising about how to write good questions/answers is really going to help anything.

What we really need is more users being genuinely helpful on a one on one basis. It will take time, but eventually it will catch on.

Answer (score 5):

Given that the SE network is always growing, I'd expect a larger *quantity* of disgruntled users on every site, including SO. I'd be curious to see whether the actual *percentage* of users having (a) bad experience(s) has trended upward. I suspect it hasn't.

Perhaps it would be beneficial to make sure users know how to use the flagging system; if a user receives a truly offensive or nonconstructive comment on a question or answer, they should flag it so that the moderators know what's happening.

If a user is reacting to down-votes as an attack on their person, well... that's kind of their problem. They've invested too much of personal stake in the process. A down-vote simply means what the hover-texts says:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not
>   useful.

It doesn't say:

> This user is a n00b and a total idiot. #lol #roflmao

One would be naive to think there aren't users having that exact sentiment when down-voting, but I find it hard to believe that those users aren't a minority on the SE network. Perhaps I simply don't engage enough to see the negativity some users complain about.

While I hate to close this answer with a question, I have to pose this to the moderators/SE staff:

*Is there an **obvious** process in place where a user who feels targeted (for whatever reason) can ask for intervention, outside of the comment/flagging system?*

Comment: it's probably hard to impossible to design system where any new user, even totally inexperienced, would be provided an easy way out. My understanding is, SE team currently tries to address this issue in a bit different way, by redesigning First Posts review to better help newcomers settle. Details of their attempt are laid out at MSE: [Let's have an explicit triage system for questions from new users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236537/165773)

Comment: Hey, can we *have* the literal text "This user is a n00b and a total idiot. #lol #roflmao" as a Reason to Close?

Comment: @Jongware In theory, you can add that as a custom close reason, but for the [love of fluffy kittens](http://www.pbh2.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/cutest-cat-gifs-kitten-playing.gif), resist that urge.

Comment: The thing is, a downvote without a comment essentially means: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful; **and I will not be bothered to explain why that's the case - nor to undo my downvote if you fix it later.**"

Comment: @einpoklum I hold most downvotes to be self-evident. I have, however, voted in the past on [a feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255710/534109) proposing StackOverflow add a "watch this question" feature. I'd retract a downvote (and have) on the rare occurrences where a question was significantly improved. If the question is truly useful/well-written (or edited to be), it will aggregate out to a positive score regardless.

Comment: @TiesonT.: I don't believe this is a rare occurrence at all, if you count it out of the _edited_ questions (rather than all problematic questions).

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes, the response is as simple as telling the OP to go back and search with google again, but using some specific search term, one that the OP was unaware of.  If the OP didn't know the right search term, they may have come up empty.

Let me illustrate with an example:  A lot of people ask variations of the same database design question.  It runs roughly like this.  I have a class/subclass situation.  I know how to handle this kind of data easily in Java.  But I have no idea how to set up tables in a relational database that will be suitable for containing subclass data.  I'm tempted to try one big table, but I don't like that.  etc. etc. etc.  Most of the rest of the question outlines their particular case, and it often expresses puzzlement that nobody ever faced a case like this before.

For some, (but  not all) of these OPs, the very best clue you can give them is to repeat the google search, using terms like "Class Table Inheritance" or "Generalization Specialization".  They often come back with a comment saying they found exactly what they needed.

This is only an illustration.  There are lots of other questions where the real problem isn't that the OP doesn't use google, but that the OP doesn't know what to look for.

Comment: +1 for the point of people trying to school question-posters rather than trying to find a way to improve the question / make the poster delete a redundant question on his/her own accord.

Answer (score 4):

I write to emphasize the following: yes, some of the loudly disgruntled writers are the unfortunate recipients of unprofessional, rude remarks. However, many more of them are recipients of entirely professional, polite, responses. If people start dropping f-bombs upon receipt of an entirely polite request for clarification, or, yes, a downvote or a closure, there's not much to be done about it except to sweep up the dropping and move on. Communal self-flagellation won't change anything.

Comment: Professional, polite responses generate very little disgruntlement, I believe. Downvotes without explanatory comments, as well as condescending comments, are much more of a common cause. And I say this based on my (limited) experience on SO vs, say, TeX.SX in which the atmosphere is much more positive in my experience.

Answer (score 3):

I say make the **home page a giant Google type search bar with an Search button** on the side and an Ask button on the resulting page after search results. At least would lead more people to searching first.

I frankly feel that the community itself is fine. Every community of a large enough size is bound to have issues like these and my opinion is that **there is a perfectly acceptable balance** between users who would rudely answer to stupid questions and ones who would take their time to improve the question, answer it anyway and so on.

And frankly, some of the kind of questions that are asked on the site, especially the JavaScript tag are shockingly terrible. They are more of a *fix this for me* rather than *why this is not working?*

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to focus newbies more on searching, -1 for claiming the community is fine. (So no vote...) . As for "fix this for me" - just don't fix it for them. Make a polite comment (preferably without the downvote at first), or just walk away if you feel annoyed.

Answer (score 1):

The community does not have an attitude problem just a very few arrogant people, which give a bad name to the rest.

I like reading even if I do not need any particular knowledge. Since the beginning of June I have been stuck at home due to a temporary health issue. I've started to read Stack Overflow.

During this time, I had a chance to make some observations. There are two type of active users on Stack Overflow, I have nothing to say about group one they are helpful, never slap your mistake in your face if a question is off topic and they forward you to the correct Stack Exchange site etc.

It seems like the second group of people - as I mention very few - want to beat people with their knowledge. You can’t ask something simple, if you are not a native speaker you are a criminal. Personally, I believe they are not here for good, but something else.

I believe, just because of this situation, almost every new user starts a new question with “I am sorry, I am new here may be it is so simple but….”. I share these feelings because I can’t phrase my exact thoughts due the language barrier. It is very tough.

I have no intention to ask the community to “tolerate bad questions” or “attitude problems”.

Comment: Your first edit misrepresented mohacs answer @Infinite... mohacs I don't quite understand your last sentence. Could you explain _"I have no intention to say..."_ differently for me? I wouldn't worry too much about your English.

Answer (score -7):

Sorry, but this new user is correct (although he shouldn't have used the kind of language he did).

Joining SO as a new user is basically like being transported suddenly to the Court of Louis XIV and being expected to understand the highly complex etiquette - it really does feel as though, no matter how hard you try and how many times you try to understand the millions of complicated rules on this place, you ALWAYS end up falling foul of some arbitrary rule which you didn't know about, and which it is not reasonable to expect a new user to know about.  Then, when you get banned, you aren't even allowed to ask why you got banned!  This would be OK if it were easy to work out why you got banned, but I genuinely still have no idea why I got banned from SuperUser, and therefore have no idea how to get my SU access back - since I don't know what I did wrong (and can't work it out by repeatedly reading the rules), and therefore can't fix it.  This IS extremely frustrating, and frankly, the culture of overzealous moderation here is ruining SO, and turning it into a place which works for a relatively small number of purists, but doesn't work for the millions of people who could benefit from it.

Finally, another thing - I had a perfectly reasonable answer downvoted on the History StackExchange, not because it broke any rules or was an inappropriate question, but simply because other users disliked my viewpoint based on subjective opinion.  It seems wrong to me that this is treated in the same way as an answer which is downvoted on CrossValidated because it is objectively wrong.  Allowing downvotes because people subjectively disagree with an opinion, rather than because it's objectively wrong, will lead to dangerous herd behaviour and consensus-forming on the History (or other humanities) SEs.

Comment: For the part about Stack Overflow: try making your point without exaggerating. For the part about Super User: you do not get question banned out of the blue, but try posting on their Meta site (and explain your case **without** ranting). For the part about History: people are allowed to vote as they see fit, and if there were rules it wouldn't be possible to enforce them anyway.

Comment: While we do have some expectations in terms of quality, phrasing it like we have unattainable rules, without even showing any concrete examples of "overzealous moderation", will not make a good argument.

Answer (score -13):

SO is awesome, but the sad fact is some people are so small-minded that they actually let SO reputation give them a big head, and off they go on a power trip.

95% of the posts on SO are respectful and only call out things that need calling out.  There's that 5% though, and you can just feel it when you read it, that they are getting off to throwing their weight around.

Yes, this is a lot like high-school mentality.  Now I'm a Sophomore so I'm going to pick on the freshman.

Rep is just a fun aspect to the whole thing, that makes it more interesting and engaging.

Rep does not mean you are a better programmer/thinker/human being.

Comment: In my limited experience, it's a lot more of than 5%. But - when counting comments, downvotes and close votes, not answers; people who invest the effort in answering you probably like you/your question enough to not be derisive generally.

Answer (score -31):

I've seen a lot of rudeness on Stack Exchange too, and it's down to the current design of the system and the community that resists ideas that could improve it.

```
Internet + anonymity + reputation system = rudeness
```

**I'm certain that Stack Overflow would work just as well if you removed the *entire* reputation system.** This idea is resisted because users will lose reputation.

I'd certainly participate more, but I don't because of the irrelevant user conversations and noise on the site, and needless computation which results in using it only when I need something (either help or boredom relief).

I'm also certain that that is true for **a lot** of other users.

Receiving downvotes on this is fine by me because it shows exactly how intolerant the community is.

Even if the system can't be removed it would be nice to have a user setting on Stack Exchange sites that allows you to switch off seeing all visual elements of the reputation system.

Comment: [This was made in the context of questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265419/456814), but it applies equally well to answers, such as this one. It's just a common sense discussion thing, really.

Comment: This shows just how nice the community here is - as soon as I make this suggestion I get a slew of revenge downvotes on my main SO profile. Good Job community you're really proving your quality

Comment: You made a bunch of edits within the last 3 minutes, when your one downvote occurred. Don't make the common misguided mistake of assuming that just because you discuss something on Meta, that people are then going to go and "revenge" downvote you on the main site. Really, [this is hardly anything to complain about](http://i.stack.imgur.com/30ZBb.png). It's probably completely unrelated.

Comment: You present no concrete arguments to back up your statements, at best this is a rant. You put a lot of assumptions into your statements about what people participating on this site are or do, without any concrete clarification on what you're actually talking about. If you do have a particular beef with the community at large, you'll have to present your views a lot better than you are. Personally, I'm always open to hear critique of anything, but it must be well presented in order to be constructive. Yours isn't. -1

Comment: Your view on the topic would be extremely useful if well-presented, because you feel that SO is rude. You fit as the target audience of this entire discussion about "yet another disgruntled user". As Deceze said, please present the facts constructively.

Comment: I agree with you about SO working just as well without rep. We'd still need an accountability system for gaining certain privileges to avoid an onslaught of crap, but the rep system as it stands just creates a hierarchy of people who consider themselves "above" new users. We'd get rid of a lot of "rep-farming" and abusive behavior if we'd stop giving people the incentive to do dumb stuff for internet points. It's never going to happen, but I see where you're coming from.

Comment: @eddie_cat: Please outline how your non-rep rep-system would be better, and why, *in detail*. At the moment, your comment is not constructive and slightly offensive. Anyway, is someone trusted, with a better reputation (general term, not meaning our imperfect system here) *not* better (in that context) than someone who has none (that does not or should not translate to entitlement)?

Comment: Not sure why you're offended. What I meant by "do dumb stuff" was people who try to game the system for points or badges. I do think we should have some sort of metric for determining who has more experience with the site, who has certain privileges, etc. And I do think voting is important for the site, obviously. I'm just not convinced that having people compete for rep which is displayed on their profile is a good thing. I think it can create bias in voting, along with lots of butthurt people complaining on meta. I don't have some giant system change to propose, or I would do so. [cont]

Comment: I know it'll never happen. But I do sometimes wonder if it would be better to simply have tiers of users, new, experienced, and expert or something along those lines and have that be the only displayed metric. The rep system could go in the background and be used for privilege-unlocking & nothing about audits/moderation would need to change. Just an idea.

Comment: Your point makes no sense. Jon Skeet, the user with the biggest reputation here, is an **extremely nice person**, who descends from the top of the hill to teach every poor bastard how to do things he could have been long bored of. And most high-rep users are just as good. The fact you don't have lots of rep is because you're entitled and didn't get the memo on "how **you too** need to be a good person". *Stop whining.*

Comment: Clara, time has proved the authenticity of the points you made in your answer. It is very unfortunate to see that you really did receive massive downvotes on SO after posting this answer.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion um, why did you just add whitespace to the end of this answer?

Comment: @Cupcake: To remove my downvote from this post. The scenario has changed since the time I cast that vote. I was in dilemna whether I should or shouldn't edit.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion fair enough, but if I was in your situation, I would probably have tried to improve the post by making it less-ranty, more neutral and objective...but that's just me personally, and also the answer may be beyond saving, without radical adjustments from the author herself.

Comment: Most of the observations here are correct... However, they are orthogonal to the problem of rude behavior, which is an immune defense in any established population. Also, if there was no official rep system the folks here would just create there own - again, this is just something you have to either expect and work with or... Well, let it blindside you.

Comment: There's two problems with this answer. Firstly the suggestion that SO would work just as well without rep points is unproven, and is a risky proposition. My view is the gamification system is the very reason for its success - I suspect users get a small endorphin hit when they get a rep increment. It makes the site addictive, which is (mostly) a good thing.

Comment: The second issue is drawing a correlation between downvotes and community intolerance. It is worth bearing in mind that downvotes on Meta have a different meaning - it is not that your post is bad _per se_, it just means people disagree with it. Consider also the ramifications of interpreting downvotes as intolerance: that would mean you could give the worst, most insulting or least helpful answer here, but a downvote would make _me_ intolerant. That approach to voting tries to delegitimise my voting privilege, and takes the view that what you have written is beyond disagreement.

Comment: In your defence, I do somewhat agree that even perfect meritocracies can develop hierarchies - a class system if you will - where people might be subconsciously assigned a lowly or grand status. Their contributions are then viewed in this light, such that a question with minor quality problems is downvoted if they are of 1-rep and treated more leniently if they are an established user. However, I am not sure what we can do to resolve that, since removing the rep system might do more harm than good.

Comment: @halfer: I agree with you on downvotes on meta. I am an active voter too. But OP recieved a huge backlash on SO proper after this answer here, which is actually an abuse of downvoting privilege by the community.This behaviour is why Cupcake posted [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268171/2982225) and I posted [this comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268099/yet-another-disgruntled-new-user/268241?noredirect=1#comment75426_268103) and Shog [wrote this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268099/yet-another-disgruntled-new-user/268241?noredirect=1#comment75456_268103)