# Where is a list of posting criteria?

Tags: support, scope, help-center

How do I know what to post so people don't downvote? They vote without explaining: I don't know why.

How do I know where I can post, too? Some sections give me errors and make we wait to post.

Why?  I need info for a mobile device, not pc.

Comment: Try the FAQ, right there under 'help'.

Comment: First off, please take a little extra time to clean up your English in your questions, as I did here. The system will attempt to block txtspeak and other problematic language, which is an indication that you should rephrase your question in proper English. Having a clearly written question can really help its reception and the likelihood you'll get a good answer.

Comment: Using a spell checker or asking a friend to read your questions before you post might help too.

Comment: I'm on a phone.  Where is the information posted on the phone? I'm just trying to figure out what people want when I post so it's not voted down.  I just wasted an hour formulating a question that no one bothered to answer but only voted down. I don't understand what I did wrong of no one explains.

Comment: One person said I need to add code directly in post but I've been told to not do that as well. And sorry, my phone spell check isn't the best.

Comment: you were presented with several screens covering all this before you were allowed to submit your first question.

Comment: Simply start by reading your own question before you post it. Is it legible? Can its presentation be improved (spelling, grammar, formatting etc.)? Would *you* want to *read* this? Would you want to figure out what the problem is this person is having? Does this seem answerable? Does this seem like time well spent if you started typing an answer?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any friends.  I Just moved so I'm all alone. I just want people to answer my java questions and is voted down instead. Just wish I could comment so I don't have to post near duplicates cause often ill have a similar question but have to start a new post cause I cant comment and then people mark I ft as duplicate preventing me from doing anything. Im just confused and looking for help as to what im doing wrong besides spelling mistakes

Comment: You should always be able to comment on your own question (is that not so? I've never lived with that restriction... ^_^;;). Also, don't post duplicates, edit your question to improve it. Yes, even after it has been closed; if the improvements make it better, it'll be reopened.

Comment: Also maybe see this take on the matter: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268121/476 (the part about the coffee machine being the most important)

Comment: @deceze: He's talking about commenting on existing questions/answers to get some clarification. This is an interesting point, actually: dupe-closing happens quite often when an OP is expected to "read around the edges" of an existing Q&A, but what if that Q&A _just_ missed what they needed? Commenting on it with a new question is disallowed to. So what then?

Comment: @Lightness Ah, I see what you mean now. Well, the existing policy is to post a new question, explicitly referring to the old question, stating one's situation and why the old question doesn't work for it and/or clarifying the shortcomings of the other Q&A. Essentially, post a good self-contained question, but clarify why existing solutions don't apply to it. I'd think that also has better chances of receiving an answer than commenting on a potentially very old question.

Comment: How can I delete this question

Comment: @cjayem13: Why would you do that? We've all spent time writing information for you on it. Why are you trying to undo all that work? See this sort of crappy behaviour is why everybody keeps bloody downvoting you.

Comment: the downvotes is why i want to remove. I've tried editing but it's keep s getting voted down.  not trying to be crappy, just don't want to keep losing points.. what should I do instead to stop losing points on this question?  it's obviously not a good question but i dont get why people vote it down again as if I don't know that now..  I'm not trying to waste people's time I'm just confused

Comment: @deceze: "the existing policy is to post a new question" -> And where does this policy being stated upon? The FAQ seems to [suggest editing the question and asking it to be reopened](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions). If the "policy" is an informal etiquette that I need to learn by hanging in SO for some time, then it is not really a policy, isn't it?

Comment: when I edit a question, why do I have to choose "bug", "feature request", discussion, support as tags?  If I were to post this as a question would it be voted down too? Why? thanks

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit I'm not understanding and people obviously don't like the question. I thought taking away something people don't like would be good, not crappy. I'm at a loss.

Comment: @Ibrahim We're talking about two different things. If **your own** question got closed for some reason, you're expected to improve it and it will be reopened. What Lightness pointed out was the case where you stumble across an existing solution which doesn't quite fit your needs, but which you also can't comment on.

Comment: @cjayem13: Downvotes on meta do not incur any loss in reputation ("points"), so you do not need to worry about it. Please, read the documentation you've been linked to.

Comment: @cjayem13 You are not losing points for posts **on Meta**. The voting here is to express agreement or disagreement, it does not impact your reputation. And you have to chose one of those tags because every post on Meta should fall into one of those categories.

Comment: @cjayem13: _"when I edit a question, why do I have to choose 'bug', 'feature request', 'discussion', 'support' as tags_" Why do you think you shouldn't have to?

Comment: BTW, in case you still haven't found the link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit o0o okay! I didn't know that. That definitely alleviates some of my frustration.  I thought people were voting down because they thought I was wasting their time which honestly upset me cause I was asking for help to avoid getting downvoted, especially for longer posts regarding coding problems.   Much apologies, I wasn't trying to be crappy, I was trying to avoid wasting people's time assuming everyone was pissed at me.  Thank you though for sticking with me an assisting! :-)  I'm reading the info via the link in the answer now.

Comment: Note that downvotes on SO proper (i.e. on your programming questions) _do_ result in a reputation decrease.

Comment: The question rating is super subjective; high reputation users insist that "not useful' is the only reason questions get downvoted.  There's a calibration here that involves months of asking questions and learning what voters think is useful and not useful.  The FAQ is a start, but there's obviously more to it than that.  I don't think that up/downvoting a question involves reputation, so I guess the unexperienced just follow the FAQ and don't worry about getting downvoted.   It is what it is.  And yes, if you edit based on comments, the rating may well change.

Comment: The related questions section is often more helpful than searching yourself, so there's that too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link in the sidebar on the page where you ask your questions.

[image: How to Ask]

There you will find all sorts of guidelines on how to ask good questions.

Also, people do appear to be posting comments on your questions, so use that feedback.

Comment: I tried on meta but it gave errors when posting. it said not the right type and doesn't meet standards so i copied and pasted here.

Comment: The link was very helpful. Thank you